Ubuntu crashes randomly and there is segfault error in syslog
I get the following syslog error while I am working on Nvidia Omniverse. I don't have any idea what the issue is. This is a new install of Ubuntu, and the only way to get the computer to run again is to shut it down, reinstall RAM and turn it on.

2024-07-18T18:52:28.669246+02:00 selimUbuntu kernel: omni-tagging-se[3465]: segfault at 6876bc98 ip 000070a96ad2f7bd sp 00007ffd2b1b0fb0 error 6 in libpython3.10.so.1.0[70a96ac00000+409000] likely on CPU 7 (core 1, socket 0)
2024-07-18T18:52:28.669256+02:00 selimUbuntu kernel: Code: 83 ec 08 48 8b 6f 08 48 8b 85 88 01 00 00 48 85 c0 74 1c f6 85 a9 00 00 00 40 75 21 40 89 fb ff d0 f6 85 a9 00 00 00 40 74 05 <48> 83 4b f8 01 48 83 c4 08 5b 5d c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f6 47 f8
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00


Segfault can be two things bad ram or bad code in a program. If it happens as soon as you install the OS I lean towards bad ram. Your question does need to be edited and include the version of Ubuntu you are using.
